# Oracle Connection is what is the problem and is it going to work ? C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

When i run this program i get the next exception: Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in Connection1.exe
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Connection1.exe
Additional information: De type-initialisatiefunctie for Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection made an exeption;
Problem i get:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TByyP.png

```cs
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
class GetSchemaSample
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int Klok_id = 1;
        string Reden = "DIENST";
        string InUit = "i";

        string constr = "Data Source=MyDataSource;User Id=MyId;Password=MyPassword;";
        var query = "Insert INTO KLOK(KLOK_ID, REDEN,INUIT) VALUES(" + Klok_id + ",'" + Reden + "','" + InUit + "')";
    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(constr))
    {
      try
      {
        conn.ConnectionString = constr;
        conn.Open();
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(*conn*);
                OracleTransaction txn = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
                try
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = query;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    txn.Commit();
                    Console.WriteLine("Record toegevoegd!");
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    txn.Rollback();
                    Console.WriteLine("Geen record kunnen toevoegen:((((((");
                }
        //Get all the schema collections and write to an XML file. 
        //The XML file name is Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client_Schema.xml
        //DataTable dtSchema = conn.GetSchema();
        //dtSchema.WriteXml(ProviderName + "_Schema.xml");
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: replace `conn` with `query`

Comment: @MindSwipe thanks that works but i get exception look above